# test significance for frequencies

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, frequency

I have frequency data for six datasets (3 control samples and 3 treated samples) consisting of values for physical stiffness, when I plot the frequencies against stiffness it looks like the treated samples display lower frequences for the same stiffness, but how can I test if it is significant?

My data for the first two columns looks like this:

```
Control_freq Control_stiff Treated_freq Treated_stiff
0.000248 4.05396 0.25066 0.30044
2.03277 11.32105 2.28217 0.09013
4.06529 11.53126 4.31367 0.33049
6.09781 11.38111 6.34517 0.2704
```